# practicing SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT with FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create prevents order from employee who isn't server. This is my  [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC8Dw.png) for the project. My code I created runs fine but I still can INSERT with the employee who's not the 'server'

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.chk_server_position(@employee_ID int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position varchar(50);
    DECLARE @employeeID int;
    DECLARE @output varchar(50);
    SELECT @position = employee.position, @employeeID = orderInfo.employee_ID
    FROM employee, orderInfo
    WHERE employee.employee_ID = orderInfo.employee_ID
    IF (@position = 'server')
        SET @output = 'true'
    return @output;
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE orderInfo
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_position CHECK (dbo.chk_server_position(employee_ID) = 'true')
```

Apparently I've changed the code to this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.chk_server_position(@employee_ID int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position varchar(50);
    DECLARE @employeeID int;
    DECLARE @output varchar(50);
    SET @employeeID = (SELECT employee_ID FROM orderInfo)
    SET @position = (SELECT position FROM employee, orderInfo
                    WHERE employee.employee_ID = orderInfo.employee_ID AND employee.employee_ID = @employee_ID)

    IF (@position = 'server')
        SET @output = 'true'
    return @output;
END;
GO
```

And now I got error message 
**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**
when running

```
ALTER TABLE orderInfo
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_position CHECK (dbo.chk_server_position(employee_ID) = 'true')
```

Which approach is closer to result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved the problem with `TRIGGER`

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_employee_position
ON orderInfo
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @employeeID INT = (SELECT i.employee_ID FROM inserted i);
    SET @position = (SELECT position FROM employee WHERE employee_ID = @employeeID)
    IF (@position = 'server')
        INSERT INTO orderInfo(employee_ID, tableNo) VALUES (@employeeID, (SELECT i.tableNo FROM inserted i))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're records always inserted since your "last selected" employee is not server, you missed filtering for given employee.

You Haven't used @employee_ID parameter in Where clause in your USP.
Modify your where clause like:
`WHERE employee.employee_ID = orderInfo.employee_ID and employee.employee_ID = @employee_ID`

Update:
Why you need to select @EmployeeID In USP? You could have written just like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.chk_server_position(@employee_ID int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position varchar(50);
    DECLARE @output varchar(50) = 'false';

    SELECT @position = position FROM employee
    inner join orderInfo ON employee.employee_ID = orderInfo.employee_ID
    WHERE employee.employee_ID = @employee_ID)

    IF (@position = 'server')
        SET @output = 'true'
    return @output;

END;
GO
```

Comment: tried, still doesn't work, I still can insert order with employee_ID who isn't 'server'